# LinkedIn API unable to retrieve results

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I used an API to retrieve a list of people on LinkedIn according to some details but whenever I run the API no results are returned.

```
import requests
import json

endpoint = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people-search'
access_token = "Token"
params = {
   ' title': 'full stack developer',
}

headers = {
  'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)

response_json = json.loads(response.text)

search_results = response_json['elements']

for result in search_results:
  name = result['title']['text']
  location = result['subline']['text']
  print(f'{name} - {location}')
```